# How can I access a superclass class variable from a subclass in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

I am trying to access a class variable from a subclass. I understand that class variables are not inherited which answers the question of why the code does not work, however I don't fully understand how I can work around it.

This is my code:

```
Class A
  ...
  class << self 
    def format(a, b)
      @format = a
    end

    def item(a, b)
      @item[a] = b
    end

  end
end

Class B < A
  format 4, 7

  item 7, 12
  ...
end

Class C < B
  item 7, 18
end
```

Running the following in a irb session

```
B.format => 4
C.format => nil
```

So understanding that class variables aren't inherited, is it possible to make `C.format => 4` or will I need to refactor as such:

```
Class B < A
  format 4, 7
  item 7, 12
end

Class C < A
  format 4, 7
  item 7, 18
end
```

My reason for wanting to avoid the latter is that I have a lot of variables defined in that same way (calling a function to set a class variable) and I don't want to have to duplicate all the code across class B and C  because one instance variable differs.

Comment: why don't you create a module and put the variables (maybe as attr_accessors) there?

Comment: There are no class variables in your code. Do you mean instance variables?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to define a class you need to use the keyword `class` not `Class`.

Secondly, there is no reason to pass the method `A::format` an argument it does not use. I therefore changed it to have just one argument.

Thirdly, after defining `A`, when `A.item` is first executed an exception will be raised because `@item` has not been defined. Specifically, `@item` (like any other undefined instance variable) will return `nil` when called and `nil` has no no method `[]`. I therefore changed the method `item` to initialize the class instance variable (not class variable) `@item` to an empty array.

```
class A
  class << self 
    def format(a)
      @format = a
    end    
    def item(a, b)
      @item = []
      @item[a] = b
    end
  end
end
```

```
class B < A
  format 4
  item 7, 12
end
```

```
class C < B
  item 7, 18
  def self.format
    superclass.instance_variable_get(:@format)
  end
end
```

It is my understanding that you want a method `C::format` to return the value of `B`'s instance variable `@format`.

```
C.format
  #=> 4
```

If one attempts to execute `B.format` an exception will be raised because `B::format` requires two arguments. If `B.format` is meant to return the value of `B`'s class instance variable `@format` you need to write:

```
B.instance_variable_get(:@format)
  #=> 4
```

You might add read and write accessors for the the instance variable `@format`, in which case your code would be simplified somewhat:

```
class A
  class << self
    attr_accessor :format
    def item(a, b)
      @item = []
      @item[a] = b
    end
  end
end
```

```
class B < A
  @format = 4
  item 7, 12
end
```

```
class C < B
  item 7, 18
  def self.format
    superclass.format
  end
end
```

```
C.format
  #=> 4
```

Comment: In the example `class B < A; format = 4; item 7, 12; end`. `format = 4` this will just set the local variable `format`. You need to specify the recient explicitly `self.format = 4` or set the instance variable directly `@format = 4`.

Comment: Thanks, @max. Beginner's mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that class variables are not inherited

This is completely false and you have not actually understood what class variables are.

A class variable in Ruby is declared with the `@@` sigil. And they are definitely inherited:

```
class A
  @@x= "Hello World"

end

class B < A
  puts @@x # Outputs "Hello World"
end
```

Class variables are actually shared between a class and its subclasses:

```
class Animal
  @@greating = "Hello"
  def greet
    "#{@@greating} I'm a #{self.class.name.downcase}"
  end
end

class Cat < Animal
  @@greating = "Meow"
end

class Dog < Animal
  @@greating = "Woof"
end

puts Dog.new.greet # Woof I'm a dog
puts Cat.new.greet # Woof I'm a cat
puts Animal.new.greet # Woof I'm a animal
```

As you can see from the example this can often lead to unexpected and undesireable effects. And class variables are not considered thread safe.

What you are actually setting is referred to as a [*class instance variable*](https://www.codegram.com/blog/understanding-class-instance-variables-in-ruby/) - this is just a instance variable except that its scope is not a instance of A. Instead its scope is the singleton class A which is an instance of the Class class.

Unlike true class variables which have their own sigil *class instance variables* are not shared between a class and its subclasses as thier scope is [the singleton class](https://medium.com/@leo_hetsch/demystifying-singleton-classes-in-ruby-caf3fa4c9d91). Every subclass its own singleton class.

```
class Animal
  @greating = "Hello"

  def self.greeting
    @greating
  end

  def greet
    "#{self.class.greeting} I'm a #{self.class.name.downcase}"
  end
end

class Cat < Animal
  @greating = "Meow"
end

class Dog < Animal
  @greating = "Woof"
end

puts Dog.new.greet # Woof I'm a dog
puts Cat.new.greet # Meow I'm a cat
puts Animal.new.greet # Hello I'm a animal
```

*Class instance variables* are actually far more useful then true class variables. If you want to simulate the inheritance of *class variables* with *class instance variables* you can do it with the [Class#inherited](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Class.html#method-i-inherited) callback provided by Ruby:

```
class A
  @x = [self.name]
  class << self
    attr_accessor :x
    def inherited(subclass)
      puts "#{subclass.name} is inheriting from #{self.name}"
      subclass.x = x
      subclass.x.push(subclass.name)
    end
  end
end

class B < A; end # outputs "B is inheriting from A"
class C < B; end # outputs "C is inheriting from B"
puts B.x.inspect # => ['A', 'B']
puts C.x.inspect # => ['A', 'B', 'C']
```